# Mysql like '%search%' not found with concat colums

Tags: mysql, sql-like, concatenation

I create this table:

```
create table if not exists `example`(
`firstNames` varchar(45) not null,
`secondNames` varchar(45) not null)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Now I insert one row:

```
insert into example values('Jose Alonzo', 'Pena Palma');
```

And a check if is correct

```
select * from example;

| firstNames | secondNames |
----------------------------
| Jose Alonzo|  Pena Palma |
```

Its ok!
Easy
Now I create a statment to search this row

```
set @search = 'jose alonzo pena';
select * from example
where concat(firstNames, ' ', secondNames) like concat('%',@search,'%');
```

This return

```
| firstNames | secondNames |
----------------------------
| Jose Alonzo|  Pena Palma |
```

Now I change the value @search for 'jose pena'

```
set @search = 'jose pena';
select * from example
where concat(firstNames, ' ', secondNames) like concat('%',@search,'%');
```

And do not return nothing!

```
| firstNames | secondNames |
```

What is happening?
I can't use like for characters that are in the middle of the varchar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot use like for characters that are in the middle of the string.  Or, in other words, a space character matches a space character, not an arbitrary string of characters.  The following would match:

```
where concat(firstNames, ' ', secondNames) like concat('%', replace(@search, ' ', '%'), '%')
```

The order would be important, so this would match `concat(firstNames, ' ', secondNames)` but not `concat(secondNames, ' ', firstNames)`.

If you are interested in these types of searches, you should investigate [full text indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html).  In addition to being more powerful, they are also faster.

Comment: Thank you!
That was exactly what I wanted.